# How to schedule a task to be executed in the future even the phone is switched off

Tags: android, scheduled-tasks

I need to schedule a task (e.g. Send email or switch the phone off) to be executed **in some date and time in the future** (e.g. June 12 2013 at 3:00PM)

I want them multiple tasks, different timing, persistent even the phone is switched off.

I have searched but the results are sorta confusing. Can any one please guide me to the solution ?

Answer (score 2):

> I need to schedule a task (e.g. Send email or switch the phone off)

You do not have rights to "switch the phone off", unless you are building your own firmware.

> to be executed in some date and time in the future (e.g. June 12 2013 at 3:00PM)

A year out is a bit unusual.

> I want... persistent even the phone is switched off.

That is not possible, unless by "switched off" you mean "in sleep mode". In that case, tactically, [use `AlarmManager`, with a `_WAKEUP`-style alarm](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html).

That being said, `AlarmManager` is not exactly designed for stuff a year in the future. You may want to just schedule events for the next week's worth of stuff, including an event to have you schedule the next week's worth of events.

And, if the phone is truly switched off (i.e., "Power Off" after long-pressing the POWER button), your alarms do not go off, and you will need to reschedule them when the device is turned back on.

Comment: Ok Forget about the "Year" but may be after 2 months on Wed June 13 at 2:00 PM ?. Also switching it off wont be so important. And I think keeping them persistent will done be storing the info in a database or so, why you see not possible ?

Comment: @MHassen: "may be after 2 months" -- I would still keep a shorter range of events in `AlarmManager` (e.g., a week's worth). "I think keeping them persistent will done be storing the info in a database or so" -- that's fine, just so long as you understand that Android will not save your event schedule automatically.